# when write URL manually in address bar get error 404 in the page

Tags: url, iis, iis-10

I have a server that I configure It,
It work correctly, Today I test write an address like this manually,
http://samplesite.com/research/home

I got error 404 
If I go to this page step by step it work correct(write url "domain name" in the address bar and then click on links to navigate to above address). But why when I write address in the address bar by hand it's not work,
I test many ways:

- After navigate by click to this page(that worked correct), copy and past this address to another browser, but not work,
- remove http:// from address but not work
- add http:// manually  but not work

what is my mistake in IIS configuration? (my server is windows server 2016 , IIS 10 and my project develop by .net core 2.2)

UPDATE:
My Project is in mvc .net core 2.2, I don't change my application route config and about click step by step, yes if i open my site like http://example.com and then click on hyperlink it work correct but if copy the correct address and past in another tab don't work and get Error 404

Comment: Could you please tell me the details information about your asp.net core 2.2 application? Is this application is mvc or api or razor page? Could you please share the details route config for the application?  Could you please explian more about "If I go to this page step by step it work correct(write url "domain name" in the address bar and then click on links to navigate to above address)"? Do you mean you click the hyperlink inside the main page to access the research home?

Comment: My Project is in mvc .net core 2.2, I don't change my application route config and about click step by step, yes if i open my site like http://example.com and then click on hyperlink it work correct but if copy the correct address and past in another tab don't work and get Error 404